# Could not load file or assembly '[Website]' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

My apologies if this has been answered in the past.  I have searched high and low for an answer, but none of the suggestions on previous posts fixed my problem.  That is why I am posting this question.

I am converting a web service that previously ran under 2003/IIS6 to 2008 R2/IIS7.  I am new to 2008 R2/IIS7 so my apologies if it is a simple fix that I am not familiar with.

I created a custom Application Pool called ILXQuoteServer, but modeled it after the Classic .Net Application Pool so all configurations in both pools match.

When I got the above error, I reset all the application permissions to use [local host]\network services and gave [local host]\network services read/execute/list permissions on the web service folder.

However, none of these fixes worked.  Here's the full error.  Hopefully, it's a simple fix.

Thanks.

Han

==================================================================

**Server Error in '/ILXQuoteServer' Application.**

*Could not load file or assembly 'ILXQuoteServer' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.*

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'ILXQuoteServer' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Assembly Load Trace:** The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'ILXQuoteServer' could not be loaded.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = Unknown
LOG: DisplayName = ILXQuoteServer
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/MA Install/ILXQuoteServer/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\MA Install\ILXQuoteServer\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\MA Install\ILXQuoteServer\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/ilxquoteserver/70368188/9ded7e96/ILXQuoteServer.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/ilxquoteserver/70368188/9ded7e96/ILXQuoteServer/ILXQuoteServer.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/MA Install/ILXQuoteServer/bin/ILXQuoteServer.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\MA Install\ILXQuoteServer\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070005). Probing terminated.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'ILXQuoteServer' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'ILXQuoteServer, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +43
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +127
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +142
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'ILXQuoteServer, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +203
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +105
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName) +54
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +232
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +51
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +337

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'ILXQuoteServer, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +58
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +512
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) +729

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'ILXQuoteServer, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8921851
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +259

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5456; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try giving permissions to the accounts on the Temporary ASP.NET files folder?

On most machines it is located at: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files